# Operations with a list made up of custom types

Tags: haskell

I'm pretty new to Haskell, and I'm struggling with something specific. Namely, having a list that contains a series of custom types. So far, this is where I'm at:

```
type shots = [(Float,Float)]

value :: shots -> [Float]
value [(a,b)] = [(10-(sqrt(a^2+b^2)))]
```

Now, this seems to be working, but only for one pair of float values. What I'm trying to do here is, put in a series of float pairs, calculate with the equation, then return the result in a list of floats. I understand why it doesn't take any more in its current form (because of `a` and `b`), but no matter how I try to work it into a head-tail loop, it ceases to function. Tried using `fst` and `snd` as well, with no success.

Comment: You are looking for the `map` function.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I want to point out that it is impossible to make a type that starts with a lowercase letter. Type names that start with a lowercase letter are reserved for type variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to learn the building blocks as well.  For example you can write your function for a pair and then `map` it to a list of pairs.

```
f (a,b) = 10 - sqrt(a^2 + b^2)

> map f [(3,4),(5,12)]
[5.0,-3.0]
```

or defined within the context of your function

```
value = map f
   where f (a,b) = 10 - sqrt(a^2 + b^2)
```

where GHC can infer the type

```
> :t value
value :: Floating b => [(b, b)] -> [b]
```

Comment: This definitely works, but is there any way to integrate mapping into the already existing function somehow? So when I have the file loaded, I can just use something like `value [(2.4,6.1)(6.3,1.2)]` for example, and get the proper list somehow?

Comment: added inner function version

Answer (score 0):

Create a function `process` that does the calculation for a single pair

```
process (a, b) = (10-(sqrt(a^2+b^2)))
```

then map that function over your list of tuples

```
fmap process [(1,2),(3,4),(45,55)]
```

which will yield

```
[7.76393202250021,5.0,-61.06335201775947]
```